# What command should I use to only print out results from GTest in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, colcon

Currently I have simple parameter and publisher test nodes that is executed through colcon test. I am able to print the logs in the terminal, however, it prints all of the logs coming from the nodes

The command I'm using currently is:

```
colcon test --event-handlers console-direct+
```

What I want to know is how will I be able to filter out the other logs, and retain the logs from the GTest, like so:

```
1: [parameter_test-4] [  FAILED  ] ImuBufFixture.NewTest2 (18 ms)
1: [parameter_test-4] [----------] 3 tests from ImuBufFixture (345 ms total)
1: [parameter_test-4] 
1: [parameter_test-4] [----------] Global test environment tear-down
1: [parameter_test-4] [==========] 3 tests from 1 test suite ran. (345 ms total)
1: [parameter_test-4] [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
1: [parameter_test-4] [  FAILED  ] 2 tests, listed below:
1: [parameter_test-4] [  FAILED  ] ImuBufFixture.NewTest
1: [parameter_test-4] [  FAILED  ] ImuBufFixture.NewTest2
```